# Assign NaN to a column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The title may be off a little. I will explain this properly. I will receive a DataFrame `df` with unexpected format of one of the column called `marker`.

Sometimes, I will `marker`, mixed of single `marker` or range `marker` :

```
marker             place1       place2
45                  PQR           STU
145.0-100           ABC           DEF
267.0-175.8         GHI           KLM
```

During transformation, I need to split `marker` that contains `-` and becomes like this :

```
marker        firstkm    lastkm    place1       place2
45             45         NaN       PQR           STU
145.0-100      145.0      100       ABC           DEF
267.0-175.8    267.0      175.8     GHI           KLM
```

I can also get the following DataFrame where **all** `marker` are not a range.

```
marker    place1       place2
145.0      ABC           DEF
267.0      GHI           KLM
```

With this piece of code:

```
    #Split marker to temporary dataframe , split_m
    split_m = df.marker.str.split('-', expand=True)
    split_m.columns=['firstkm', 'lastkm'] #hitting error here
    split_m = split_km[['firstkm', 'lastkm']].replace([None], np.nan)
```

I can achieve the result I wanted if the DataFrame is like the first example I showed above. However, I am not able to achieve the result if the DataFrame is like the second example I showed. I am getting error :

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values
>   have 2 elements

I understand the error is caused by, the DataFrame unable to put any value in `lastkm`. But I don't know how to handle this..

If I print `split_m` for the second DataFrame, I will get this :

```
marker     firstkm    
145.0       145.0
267.0       267.0
```

How can I assign `np.nan` immediately to `lastkm` to produce the following result:

```
marker     firstkm   lastkm  
145.0       145.0     NaN
267.0       267.0     NaN
```

**EDIT**

Another pattern I encounter :

```
marker        firstkm      lastkm    place1       place2
45             45           NaN       PQR           STU
145.0-100      145.0        100       ABC           DEF
267.0-175.8    267.0        175.8     GHI           KLM
18.1J          18.1J        Nan       GHI           KLM
P7.991-54.3    P7.991       54.3      GHI           KLM
UPM Ex 0.5     UPM Ex 0.5   NaN       PPP           SSS
```

`UPMEx0.5` is stil acceptable. Case insensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.extract`:

```
print (df["marker"].str.extract("(?P<Start>\d+\.?\d+?)-?(?P<End>\d+\.?\d+?)?"))

   Start    End
0     45    NaN
1  145.0    100
2  267.0  175.8
```

Comment: Can you explain what the regex do? will this get rid of unwanted whitespaces?

Comment: It first matches `\d+` which is 1 or more digits, followed by an optional `.` and more `digits` in case you have a float. And then further followed by an optional `-` plus the same for digits.

Comment: To be fair the raw data originally like this 'km UPM24.0x", I already get rid of "km" and whatever it the column is the clean one. Which may consists combination of alphanumeric

Comment: If your original data is not like the one provided, please make sure you provide actual sample. From the looks of it it shouldn't change much.

Comment: I can give you example. Please take a look.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If you have both types of data, using `str.split()` with expand should already provide two columns which will not generate your error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
# create a copy of the original df, split_m
split_m = df.copy()

# create the additional required columns with default 'NaN' values
split_m.insert(1, 'firstkm', np.nan)
split_m.insert(2, 'lastkm', np.nan)

# unpack the splitted values to the columns. If nothing to unpack
# for 'lastkm', it will become None
split_m[['firstkm', 'lastkm']] = df.marker.str.split('-', expand=True)
# fill None values with np.nan
split_m.fillna(np.nan, inplace=True)

print(split_m)
```

Output:

```
        marker firstkm lastkm place1 place2
0           45      45    NaN    PQR    STU
1    145.0-100   145.0    100    ABC    DEF
2  267.0-175.8   267.0  175.8    GHI    KLM
3        145.0   145.0    NaN    ABC    DEF
4        267.0   267.0    NaN    GHI    KLM
```

New scenario with changed input:

```
# tab separated data for read_clipboard()
# please make sure that you source data 
# has a separator other than space.
'''
marker  place1  place2
45  PQR STU
145.0-100   ABC DEF
267.0-175.8 GHI KLM
145.0   ABC DEF
267.0   GHI KLM
P7.991-54.3 GHI KLM
UPM Ex 0.5  PPP SSS
'''

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard()

# #Split marker to temporary dataframe , split_m
split_m = df.copy()

# create the additional required columns with default 'NaN' values
split_m.insert(1, 'firstkm', np.nan)
split_m.insert(2, 'lastkm', np.nan)

# unpack the splitted values to the columns. If nothing to unpack
# for 'lastkm', it will become None
split_m[['firstkm', 'lastkm']] = df.marker.str.split('-', expand=True)
split_m.fillna(np.nan, inplace=True)

print(split_m)
```

Output:

```
        marker     firstkm lastkm place1 place2
0           45          45    NaN    PQR    STU
1    145.0-100       145.0    100    ABC    DEF
2  267.0-175.8       267.0  175.8    GHI    KLM
3        145.0       145.0    NaN    ABC    DEF
4        267.0       267.0    NaN    GHI    KLM
5  P7.991-54.3      P7.991   54.3    GHI    KLM
6   UPM Ex 0.5  UPM Ex 0.5    NaN    PPP    SSS
```

Comment: Hey, yours works fine! but the other solution perform faster. Thank you!

Comment: sure .. no problem

Comment: redoing your code and getting this error : `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Comment: Can you share your exact code? Maybe paste it in the question? Also, I see that you have mentioned that the pattern got changed. If thats the case, the code will have to change to adopt.

Comment: I ran my code for the new scenario that you have added to the question and it seems to be working fine. Updating my answer with the new input. Please make sure that your source data is separated by delimiter other than whitespace.